# Testcafe ClientFunction to set video currentTime property

Tags: javascript, testing, youtube, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to get the video properties using Testcafe to `play()`, `pause()`, get the current playing time, and set the current time.

The problem is that I'm hard coding the set time and ideally I'd like that to be a function that I can pass any `time` value I want.

I wrote the following simple test:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWQtB6Xv01Q';

fixture `Portal Experience playback`
  .page `${URL}`;

function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

test('Testing YouTube', async t => {
  const play = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').play());
  const pause = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').pause());
  const currentTime = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime);
  const setTime = await t.eval(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime = 5);

  await setTime;
  console.info(`Video time is ${await currentTime()}`);
  await play;
  await sleep(5000);
  console.info(`Video time is ${await currentTime()}`);
  await pause;

});
```

The `play`, `pause`, and `currentTime` I can just copy and past to a class inside a page model.

The page model would be:

```
export class Player {
  constructor () {
    this.play = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').play());
    this.pause = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').pause());
    this.currentTime = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime);
  }

  // a function to set video time

}
```

How do I turn `setTime` into a function inside a page model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `time` parameter in your `setTime` client function:

```
ClientFunction((time) => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime = time);
```

Modifyed test:

```
test('Testing YouTube', async t => {
    const play        = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').play());
    const pause       = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').pause());
    const currentTime = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime);
    const setTime     = ClientFunction((time) => document.querySelector('.video-stream').currentTime = time);

    await pause();

    await setTime(60);
    console.info(`Video time is ${await currentTime()}`);

    await play();

    await t.wait(10000);
    console.info(`Video time is ${await currentTime()}`);
});
```

We have plan to [add the `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` flag to the default Chrome flags](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-tools/issues/156). At present, you should [run your test in the following way](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#starting-browser-with-arguments):

```
testcafe "chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required" test.js
```

Result:

```
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 73.0.3683 / Windows 7.0.0

 Portal Experience playback
 Video time is 60
 Video time is 70.130405
  √ Testing YouTube


  1 passed (22s)
```